# MSBuild - Compile Mvc Project hosted on a file share (Mac OS X) - AssemblyInfo specified multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, iis, msbuild

I am trying to run MSBuild on a Windows machine against a project hosted on a Mac file share (Yes, this sounds insane.  I'll explain my rationale at the end as to not distract from the core question).

I'm using the `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012` and running the command:

> msbuild \\nlmac031\TEVA.Pulse\dotnet\LBi.Teva.Pulse\LBi.Teva.Pulse.csproj /p:Configuration="Release"

When I do this, I get this following compiler warning printed over and over until I manually kill (`Ctrl+C`) msbuild:

> CSC : warning CS2002: Source file 'Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' specified multiple times [\nlmac031\TEVA.Pulse\dotnet\LBi.Teva.Pulse\LBi.Teva.Pulse.csproj]

- I have confirmed I have read/write to the file share
- I have confirmed I can compile the `csproj` locally
- I have confirmed I can run the same command against a Windows machine hosting the same files
- I have copied over a copy of the `csproj` from my Windows machine to the Mac.  Theory was the line endings might be screwing up msbuild.

None of these mitigation steps helped.

**How can I use MSBuild to compile files hosted on a Mac?**

*Context:*

I am working on a MVC Web Application.  The Front End Developers (HTML / JS) are working on Macs and it is not feasible for them to use a Windows machine and Visual Studio.  I am trying to create a setup where they can work locally on their mac and when they update a javascript file or a mvc view (cshtml) and then see their updates in the context of the full site.

I can setup IIS to host the project from their file share, but I need a way to get the compiled dlls into their bin directory.  As I would prefer not to have to manually copy the dlls from my machine to their file share, I am investigating this approach.

If anyone has any advice on how to create a working setup for this environment over all, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Have you read through the `.csproj` and its references to ensure there are no duplicates and full paths that would break when compiled on a share? What if you `PUSHD` into it first?

Comment: The `.csproj` is fine as far as I can tell.  I can compile it with VS and MSBuild on Windows machines.  What's `PUSHD`???

Comment: `PUSHD` and `POPD` are  Windows commands with side benefit of automapping network drives, do `pushd \\nlmac031\TEVA.Pulse\dotnet\LBi.Teva.Pulse` first then try `msbuild LBi.Teva.Pulse.csproj` to eliminate posibility of issue being share-related.

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov - ran the `pushd` command, but no change.  MSBuild still spits out an inifite supply of `'Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' specified multiple times` errors.

Comment: Could you try creating an empty class library project, copying/cloning it onto the mac and building it instead? I've just tried to build from an Ubuntu VM with a samba share and it works just fine (bar some permission issues at first) with linked AssemblyInfo, with *nix line endings through git, with network share and everything, MSBuild gobbles it all up, I bet something's iffy with your project.